# Search for recently modified records in Filemaker?

Tags: filemaker

I'm using FileMaker 11 and trying to do a search that will show me only those records that have been modified or added since yesterday. I'm trying to use the Modification_timestamp field (which I think is a built-in FM field) but I can't seem to find the write syntax for the script. ANy help is appreciated.

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not built-in, you have to add timestamp fields and make sure to check the "Modification Date and Time" on the field's auto-enter tab.

The script will be like that:

```
Enter Find Mode
Set Field[ My Table::Modified On, ">=" & GetAsDate( Get( CurrentDate ) - 1 ) ]
Perform Find
```